# Does message replication on JBoss represent a significant overhead?

Tags: performance, jboss, activemq-artemis

I'm working on a legacy application, that was migrated to a modern JBoss version (Wildfly 20), and all features was maintained. This application is running in a cluster mode, with message queue replication between the nodes (only 2 nodes on cluster).

But the application deal with a huge volume of messages (more than a million) and the performance is not satisfying our customers. So, I was wondering does the message replication could represent an overhead and impact the application performance overall? Should I move the message broker to an external service, like a centralized ActiveMQ Broker?

Comment: I would suggest to operate the Message Broker as a separate service. It rarely makes sense to use the internal message broker.

Comment: It would be helpful to have the configuration of the two servers to see exactly how things are set up.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help others who may have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to what is lacking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The overhead of message replication in ActiveMQ Artemis (i.e. the JMS broker implementation shipped in WildFly 20) is generally not significant. The internal architecture of the broker is non-blocking so tasks like persisting the message to disk and replicating it across the network are actually done in parallel. I wouldn't expect replication to add significant overhead unless the network connection between the two brokers was poor.